# Reverse-DNS not correct (BIND9 DNS + ISC DHCP)

Tags: networking, dns, dhcp, bind, reverse-dns

In my home network under Ubuntu I use a BIND9 DNS server and an ISC DHCP server with Webmin.

Here are my settings:

**DNS Master Zone:**

```
Foward: home.local
Reverse: 192.168.5
```

**/etc/bind/named.conf.local:**

```
// Key
key "DHCP_UPDATER" {
 algorithm hmac-sha256;  
 secret "xxx";
};

// Forward DNS Zone
zone "home.local" {
 type master;
 file "/var/lib/bind/home.local.hosts";
 update-policy {
 grant DHCP_UPDATER zonesub any;
 };
};

// Reverse DNS Zone
zone "5.168.192.in-addr.arpa" {
 type master;
 file "/var/lib/bind/192.168.5.rev";
 update-policy {
 grant DHCP_UPDATER zonesub any;
 };
};
```

**/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf:**

```
ddns-updates on;
ddns-update-style standard;
allow unknown-clients;
allow client-updates;
ddns-rev-domainname "5.168.192.in-addr.arpa";
ddns-domainname "home.local";
option domain-search "home.local";
option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
authoritative;
default-lease-time 600;
max-lease-time 7200;

## Key
key "DHCP_UPDATER" {
 algorithm hmac-sha256;  
 secret "xxx";
}

## Forward DNS Zone
zone home.local. {
 primary 192.168.5.2;
 key DHCP_UPDATER;
}

## Reverse DNS Zone
zone 5.168.192.in-addr.arpa. {
 primary 192.168.5.2;
 key DHCP_UPDATER;
}


# HOME
subnet 192.168.5.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
 option domain-name "home.local";
 option domain-name-servers 192.168.5.2 , 8.8.8.8;
 option broadcast-address 192.168.5.255;
 option routers 192.168.5.1;
 range 192.168.5.130 192.168.5.199;
}
```

If I create a new DNS entry manually, everything is OK:

**home.local (Forward):**

```
nas.home.local.   A   3600   192.168.5.254
```

**192.168.5 (Reverse):**

```
254.5.168.192.in-addr.arpa.  PTR   3600   nas.home.local.
```

If it is created dynamically, then there is an error:

**home.local (Forward):**

```
raspi01.home.local.   A   300   192.168.5.140
raspi01.home.local.   DHCID  300   xxx
```

**192.168.5 (Reverse): [HERE IS THE PROBLEM]**

```
140.5.168.192.5.168.192.in-addr.arpa.   PTR   300   raspi01.home.local.
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: This is probably not the cause of your problem but please note that .local is reserved for mDNS and should not be used as a private TLD (it will cause problems for devices that support mDNS and other aspects of IETF ZeroConf). For a private TLD, use .home.arpa or .test instead.

Comment: In the meantime, we found the cause of the error. This entry needed to be corrected:     ddns-rev-domainname "in-addr.arpa" Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your `ddns-rev-domainname "5.168.192.in-addr.arpa"` doesn't seem to be correct. It should be always set to `"in-addr.arpa"`. (Notice how dhcpd always adds the *full* reversed IP address to the provided domain name – it does not try to guess or count; whatever domain you provided is literally just suffixed to the address.)

Comment: This was the cause of the problem! I corrected the entry 'ddns-rev-domainname "in-addr.arpa"', then restarted and it was fixed! Thank you!